# BJCP Category for Malted Cider

Tags: cider, malt, bjcp

As the title suggests, looking to confirm which BJCP 2015 category would be most appropriate for a malted apple cider.  In this recipe, the malt character comes from two sources: 1) DME boiled in water and added to the apple juice volume prior to primary fermentation, and 2) fermenting the juice/malt mixture using the yeast and trub leftover from a batch of pale ale transferred to secondary that day.  Yeast used was US-05 and I estimate about a  half gallon of pale ale remained in the carboy.  No hop notes detectable in finished cider.

I'm leaning towards "C2F-Specialty Cider/Perry" but would appreciate suggestions from any cider or BJCP experts out there to ensure this malted cider gets placed in the correct judging category.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this discussion on the BJCP forums and while a Graf / Malted Cider doesn't have a specific home yet it May if it gains popularity.

C2F is the correct category, but note a base style the wort best fits or list the malted ingredients and must portion, in my case I use second runnings so that part is easy.

C2F was confirmed by two Grand Master BJCP judges.

http://forum.bjcp.org/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=1250